# How do you print the length of each partition in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have 2000 partitions and I'm trying to run the following code snippet:

```
l = df.rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(lambda x,it: [(x,sum(1 for _ in it))]).collect()
```

Every variation of this code snippet fails with the following: `Ordinal must be >= 1`. I have no idea what this means. What do I need to do to reliably print the length of each of my partitions? I'm writing in Python and executing against Spark 2.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

use something like this 
`rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(lambda x,y: (x, len(list(y))))`